# Is there a list of "shortcuts" for special folder that Visual Studio accepts (like [AppDataFolder] or $(TargetDir))

Tags: windows, visual-studio

Whenever I build applications or libraries in Visual Studio, I would like to copy them to the respective application folders. This is usually done using "Build events" where I can mention variables or shortcuts for special folders like

1. `$(ProjectDir)`, `$(TargetDir)` etc...

- OR

2. `[AppDataFolder]`, `[DesktopFolder]` etc...

Is there any resource available that list all the possible shortcuts or environment variables like this?

---

I found a [similar question](https://superuser.com/a/1704679/863212) here which lists [all shortcuts/environment variables](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/usmt/usmt-recognized-environment-variables) that can be used in content of "system" i.e., in File Explorer address-bar etc... But this is not the same shortcuts that Visual Studio uses (`CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA`) vs `[CommonAppDataFolder]`.

Answer (score 0):

The shortcuts for Build events (`$(TargetDir)`) are not always the same as the shortcuts for system folder (`[AppDataFolder]`), but there are few similar shortcuts in both.

the shortcuts for

- Build Events (`$(TargetDir)`) - are called [**Macros**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/common-macros-for-build-commands-and-properties?view=msvc-170#list-of-common-macros) - they contain the context of the folder that the current Visual Studio Solution is running in. They also have shortcuts for system folder, whereas
- the system folders (`[AppDataFolder]`) - are called [System Folder Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/property-reference#system-folder-properties) - are not related to the current Visual Studio Project.

---

Additional Reference:

- [Macros GitHub file](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/cpp-docs/blob/main/docs/build/reference/common-macros-for-build-commands-and-properties.md#list-of-common-macros)
- [System Folders GitHub file](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/win32/blob/docs/desktop-src/Msi/property-reference.md#system-folder-properties)